# Deserialize JSON with varying properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json with varying properties like

```
{
   "userFirstName":"John",
   "userLastName":"Doe",
   "userDefined-prop1":"value1",
   "userDefined-prop2":"value2",
   "userDefined-prop3":"value3"
}
```

and I want to deserialize them in a class like this, where `UserDefined` dictionary would contain pairs like

```
{ "prop1" : "value1", "prop2" : "value2", "prop3" : "value3"}
```

Code:

```
class User
{
    [JsonProperty("userFirstName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userLastName")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userDefined")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> UserDefined { get; set; }
}
```

I wonder how to do the mapping. Maybe there is something like `[JsonPropery("userDefined-*")]` or `[JsonPropery("userDefined-[key]")]` ?

Comment: The whole thing needs to be a dictionary, ditch the class

Comment: Afaik you'll need a custom JsonConverter: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Or use JsonExtensionDataAttribute

Comment: can you change the JSON structure so the user-defined properties are in a sub-object?

Comment: @ADyson no, I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My appreciates, [Kalten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305465/kalten), that's exactly what I was searching for! My final class looks like

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("userFirstName")] public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userLastName")] public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData] Dictionary<string, JToken> _userDefined;

    public Dictionary<string, string> UserDefined => _userDefined.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Replace("userDefined-", string.Empty), x => x.Value.ToString());
}
```